# I want to port a desktop application developed using VTK, C++ and QT to web application

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, vtk

I want to port a desktop application developed using VTK, C++ and QT to web application.The glitch is that i want to do it using c++ because i don't want to loose performance of application. Is it possible to do that. And if it is then please suggest me some tools,libraries as well as best approach. And i would be highly thankful if somebody could share me proper tutorial or working example.

Comment: You may be interested in [emscripten](https://emscripten.org).

Answer (score 1):

VTK is completely machine dependent, just like QT so I don't think you can "port" your application to the web but you can surely make it accessible remotely through a web page.

You can try to use a VNC approach with something like [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC). It will allow you to give a remote access to your application running on your server. noVNC has two parts one in pure JS that interpreat the VNC protocol and one in python that pipes the VNC protocol (TCP) through a websocket.

I already done this kind of VTK/web integration and it works pretty well.